# Не юбилейная дата

Tags: слитно-раздельно

> Не юбилейная дата, но примечательная дата у газеты в этом году...

Не — слитно или раздельно. Вроде бы и утверждение, и отрицание, и к тому же союз *но*. Помогите разобраться. Пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое, что нужно делать в такой ситуации, – смотреть в словарь. Если в словаре нет слова со слитным написанием НЕ – всё, вопрос закрыт. На нет и суда нет. Потом можно попытаться разобраться, почему такого слова нет. Почему, например, "неширокий" есть, а "неузкого" нет? Так и с вашей "неюбилейной датой". Нет такого слова.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы

Comment: Существует сочетание (не)придирчивый зритель. В словаре нет слова со слитным написанием НЕ – всё, вопрос закрыт? Пишу раздельно? Или как?

Comment: А "существует" – это как? Вы сами придумали? Встречалось вам в тексте? Сколько раз? Заслуживает ли доверия источник? И так далее. Да, и во многих ли словарях смотрели или только в одном?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC60b0iTxo5BmqgNGp_ySczA Но дело не в одном слове, и я  расскажу, что меня не устраивает в вашем ответе (это я пишу не лично для вас, а для всей читательской аудитории).  1) ТЕОРЕТИЧЕСКИ подход верный: слово с приставкой НЕ должно присутствовать в словаре, но ПРАКТИЧЕСКИ это не всегда так. Частица НЕ используется для образования новых слов от прилагательных достаточно регулярно, и далеко не все они отражены в словаре.  Кроме того, новые слова не сразу попадают в словарь, но при этом уже применяются именно в утвердительном смысле и в утвердительных конструкциях.

Comment: ЧТО ЭТО ТАКОЕ? К примеру, утвердительной  конструкцией является сочетание прилагательное + существительное. В принципе можно было сказать так: для неюбилейной даты это слишком торжественный прием. (Но я не стала на нем останавливаться, это редкий случай). Итак, СЛОВАРЬ - это не гарантия для правильного написания прилагательного с приставкой НЕ и не повод для научного исследования вопроса.  Формальное решение удобно в тех случаях, когда вы контролируете тему в полном объеме, и знаете границы его применения.

Comment: 2) Прочитайте внимательно все заданные вопросы. Выбрав форму написания, вы тем не менее не ответили ни на один из них, включая конструкции с союзом НО.

Answer (score 3):

**Не юбилейная, но примечательная дата ...**  **Не юбилейная дата, но примечательная...**

1) В данном случае в определительной конструкции с союзом НО следует использовать **отрицание** (дата не юбилейная).

Практически слово "неюбилейный" вообще не употребляется из-за отсутствия в нем утвердительного смысла.

2) ***Не юбилейная дата*** – здесь НЕ относится к словосочетанию (в таких случаях всегда раздельное написание).

**Пояснение**

Обычно сопоставительные конструкции (союз НО) сравнивают с противительными (союз А):

*Сад небольшой (маленький), но красивый. Река там  не большая, а совсем маленькая.*

Но в сопоставительных конструкциях (в отличие от противительных) **выбор формы написания НЕ свободный и делается по смыслу.**

**Примеры:**

Миша переписывал ***не быстро, но чётко и без ошибок*** – раздельное написание НЕ в первой части предложения **(не быстро**  пишется всегда раздельно, одна форма написания).

***Он не мрачен***, но серьезен и задумчив – раздельное написание НЕ в первой части.

Comment: Говорите, что выбор свободный, а примеры приводите с однозначным написанием? Где логика? Кстати,  "небыстро" бывает, что пишется и слитно. Лично мне-то не нравится, но что есть, то есть.